# MongoDB - Aggregation with field containing dot

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a collection of documents in which a field name appears to have a dot:

```
{  
  "prod_id": "123",
  "prod_cost (whole)": 49
  "prod_cost (dec.)": 49
}
```

How can I effectively run an aggregation pipeline using that field?

As of now, it reports null values since it considers ")" as an additional nested field for `prod_cost (dec.)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [MongoDB version 5](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/limits/#mongodb-limit-Restrictions-on-Field-Names),

> MongoDB 5.0 adds improved support for the use of ($) and (.) in field names. There are some restrictions. See Field Name Considerations for more details.

[Field Names with Periods (.) and Dollar Signs ($)](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/dot-dollar-considerations/#field-names-with-periods--.--and-dollar-signs----)

> In most cases data that has been stored using field names like these is not directly accessible. You need to use helper methods like $getField, $setField, and $literal in queries that access those fields.

```
{ "$getField": "prod_cost (dec.)" }
```

[Sample MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/QJ4sM8fKl0f)

To access field in object, you can refer to [Query a Field in a Sub-document](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/getField/#query-a-field-in-a-sub-document) demo.

```
{
  "$getField": {
    field: {
      $literal: "prod_cost (dec.)"
    },
    input: "$productInfo"
  }
}
```

[Sample Mongo Playground (Nested object)](https://mongoplayground.net/p/jcKuhQZIcLE)

Comment: What if the document is nested e.g. {product_info: {prod_cost (dec.): 10}. In that case, it does not seem to be working

Comment: You can refer to this [Query a Field in a Sub-document](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/getField/#query-a-field-in-a-sub-document).